# Is Python (Flask) not closing the file correctly?

Tags: python, flask

I’m new to python. I have a separate flask web application that reads the ‘log.txt’ file in real time (via AJAX)
The expected result is that it shows “message 1” and 5 seconds later shows “message 2”. Then I have the below scripts to write into the files:

When I make a standalone Python script the below works (I see the first message and 5 seconds later the second message):

```
   f = sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('static/staging/stdout/discovery.log', 'w')
    print "Message 1"
    f.close()
    time.sleep(5)

    f = sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('static/log.txt', 'a')
    print "Message 2"
    f.close()
    time.sleep(5)
```

When I put it as part of a web app, and the function Is call as below, they both appear **together** after 10 seconds and not one after the other.

```
@app.route('/mywriter/')
def myApp():
    f = sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('static/log.txt', 'w')
    print "Message 1"
    f.close()
    time.sleep(5)

    f = sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('static/log.txt', 'a')
    print "Message 2”
    f.close()
    time.sleep(5)
```

I must point out at this stage that I was using `flush()` and `fsync()` but from what I understand doing `f.close()` will do both of these anyway. Besides it works when I put it as a standalone script, but not when I put it into a method as part of a webapp.

Comment: Why would you overwrite `stdout/stderr`? This is sooooo wrong on sooooo many levels. Just do proper `f.write` instead of prints. Anyway this seems to be related to the internal buffering (which can be manipulated from the outside of the code). Try inserting `f.flush()` lines after each write.

Comment: I'm directing both stdout & stderr, which works as expected. I have already mentioned that I have used 'f.flush()' already, but i'm not using f.close() as it calls the f.flush method within

Comment: listen, you are messing with one of the most important globals. Just don't. Side effects are hard to imagine. Anyway i cant reproduce your issue. How are you monitoring the file?

Comment: How would you suggest I redirect BOTH sdtout & stderr to one file then?.... I'm calling the function on a button which calls a JS function, which in turn calls that python method. To monitor the log.txt file I input i make an AJAX call every second, that will get the data from the text file and display it into a div.

Comment: dont redirect stdout and srderr. Use `.write()` method on the file instead of `print`.

Comment: The problem with that I plan to call multiple functions within this myApp method, its hard to know at which point the stderr/stdout will print, I will have to put multiple .write() after each and every method.

Comment: `print` is not for debuging. Actually its only purpose is educational. It should be avoided otherwise. For proper debuging do what most people do: use [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). You may find out that your weird issue is actually related to overwriting stdout/stderr. As I said, possible side effects are incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger in your IDE. Set a breakpoint at the first time.sleep(), and stepping through line by line you should be able to diagnose the issue much more exactly.